# Awk: to count the repeat and number in the increasing order

Tags: awk

In awk, I need to count repeat values from the tab separated file and renumber them in the increasing order.

The rows of column 3 should be compared. If it is not matching tss1 will be printed in column 5. Otherwise tss1, tss2, tss3 and so on will be printed in column 5.

My attempt: `awk -F'\t' '{$3=$3"\t" "tss"++cnt} 1' file`

```
Input file <tab separated>
chrX    Gripap1 7367120 7367120
chrX    Pim2    7455431 7455431
chrX    Pola1   90877494    90877494
chrX    Pcyt1b  *90900201*  90900201
chrX    Pcyt1b  *90900201*  90920450
```

output

```
Output file <tab separated>
chrX    Gripap1 7367120 7367120     tss1
chrX    Pim2    7455431 7455431     tss1
chrX    Pola1   90877494    90877494     tss1
chrX    Pcyt1b  *90900201*  90900201     tss1
chrX    Pcyt1b  *90900201*  90920450     tss2
```

Comment: @steeldriver. Thank you for the help. But please elaborate extensively. I am a biologist so not much comfortable with the AWK.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the awk function `gensub` to strip the non digit `[^0-9]` out from the 3rd field:

```
awk -v c=1 '{$(NF+1)="tss"((gensub("[^0-9]","","g",$3)==$4)?c:++c)}1' OFS='\t' file
```

This creates a new column `$(NF+1)` which is the string `tss` with the counting number `c` based on the comparison of the 3rd and 4th column. This is using the ternary operator `...?...:...` which is equivalent to an `if...then...else`.
The last `1` is the default awk action, i.e. print the line.

Comment: It looks like OP want increasing in tssX (e.g. tss1, tss2, tss3 ...).

Comment: @Archemar Thanks. I overlooked that detail.

Comment: @oliv. Thank you for your help. Can you please elaborate the code why 'g' is being used. After the increment upto 2, it is not starting again from 1. Output of the real file. Your help is highly appreciated.

chrNo Gene 5p_Coordinate TSS tss2
chr1 Tmem163 129574598 129574598 tss2
chr1 Ccnt2 129670740 129670740 tss2
chr1 Mapkapk2 132994120 132994120 tss2
chr1 Eif2d 133049783 133049783 tss2
chr1 Ctse 133534890 133534890 tss2
chr1 Cfh 142079988 142079988 tss2
chr1 Kcnt2 142142833 142142833 tss2
chr1 Ncf2 154655019 154655019 tss2
chr1 Smg7 154725298 154725298 tss2

Answer (score 0):

An `awk` script like this should work:

```
NR == 1 { print }
NR > 1 {
  if( $3 == last ) {
    count++
  } else {
    count = 1
  }
  last = $3
  print $1, $2, $3, $4, "tts" count
}
```

`OFS` is a tab by default, and tab-separated input also works with tabs.  So with this awk script in `script.awk`:

```
$ awk -f script.awk inputfile
```

Comment: Thank you for the awk script. Please explain me why it is counting from the 2nd rows. It is excluding 1st row. If I want to start counting from the first line (in case of no header), what is required modification? Also please explain, the changes.

Comment: If there is no header, remove the first line, and also remove the `NR > 1` filter on the main code block.  Your example input had a header, which is why it was written to account for one.